# How to extract City From Purchase Address Column using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new column in df called a city

This is how the column looks like in df data frame:

```
   **Purchase Address**
   917 1st St, Dallas, TX 75001
   682 Chestnut St, Boston, MA 0221
```

My Expected output should be a new column in df called a city where values between the comma (,) should be in place for example......

```
   **City**
   Dallas
   Boston
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code will work if you don't have any NA values in the address column and the format of address is fixed.

```
df['city']=[x.split(',')[1] for x in df['Purchase Address'].values]
```

Comment: thank you.. But the address column is named as Purchase Address with space in between, so it cannot identify address column....